# How to recursively replace duplicated commas in text string in a single regex using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to recursively replace duplicated commas in text string in a single regex using javascript ? My current code:

```
var myval = "aaa,,,,bbb,,,,,,,ccc,,,,,,,,ddd,,,,,,,eee";
do {
  myval = myval.replace(/,,/g, ',');
} while (myval.indexOf(",,") > 0);
console.log(myval);
```

Comment: `myval.replace(/,+/g, ',');`

Comment: I believe rock321987's comment is aleady an answer. You can use online regex testers to experiment with regular expressions. Example: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3):

Just a little bit modification in `replace`

```
myval.replace(/,+/g, ',');
```

```js
var myval = "aaa,,,,bbb,,,,,,,ccc,,,,,,,,ddd,,,,,,,eee";
myval = myval.replace(/,+/g, ',');
document.write(myval);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this:

```
myval.replace(/,+/g, ',')
```

It will replace any string of 1 or more commas (i.e. `,,,,,,`) with just one `,`

In you RegEx, you select 2 commas `/,,/`, however this selects any amount larger than `0`.

Also, the code you posted seemed to work fine in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vnhybbf/)

Comment: It's not correct. It will replace only first appearance of a series of comma.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Thanks for informing me, that was a typo, I forgot the `g`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a positive lookahead:

```
var myval = "aaa,,,,bbb,,,,,,,ccc,,,,,,,,ddd,,,,,,,eee";
myval.replace(/,+(?=,)/g, '') // prints "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee"
```

This approach will clear the string from unnecessary commas, without modifying the single ones.
See the working [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/poxemakuki/1/edit?js,console).